# Firebase login with android fragment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-snackbar

I create and login form with firebasae when the credentials is correct it's shows an snackbar.but it didn't work.Credentials are correct and code run properly without any crashes.What is the error in this code ? How can i solve this problem ?

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

View v;
EditText input_email,input_password;
Button btnLogin;
LinearLayout activity_login;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private Snackbar snackbar;

public Fragment1() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    input_email = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    input_password = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    btnLogin = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.login_btn_login);
    btnLog

in.setOnClickListener(this);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.login_btn_login) {
            LoginUser(input_email.getText().toString(),input_password.getText().toString());
        }
    }
    private void LoginUser(String email,String password)
    {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity_login,"Authenticating Completed..",4000);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: is it ur `onComplete` method call ?

Comment: I just remove the loginuser part and check the code.it's not work either.

Comment: public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.login_btn_login)
        {
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity_login, "Authenticating Completed..", 4000);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }

Comment: sorry to say didn't understand what u write above ..

Answer (score 0):

Check for error or exception,

```
if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    snackbar = Snackbar.make(activity_login,"Authenticating Completed..",4000);
                    snackbar.show();
                }else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
               }
        });
```